# Время жизни объекта

Tags: .net, c#

В некотором блоке создан анонимный объект и объект в "слабой ссылке":

```
//first object System.Random
string result=new Random().Next(0,1)==1 ?
  "equal 1":"sory, but not equal 1";

//second object System.Random 
string result=((Random)new WeakReference(new Random()).Target).Next(0,1)==1 ?
  "equal 1":"sory, but not equal 1";

GC.Collect();
```

**Вопрос:** Какой из помеченных комментариями объектов имеет большие шансы остаться в живых после сборки мусора что вызванна явно в конце примера? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Хороший вопрос, но точного ответа на него, к сожалению, не существует.*

В стандарте языка нет четкого определения механизма работы `GC.Collect()` и семантики очистки объектов, обернутых слабыми ссылками. Т.е, если говорить кратко, то ответ - **implementation specific**, т.к, скажем, под некоторой сферической реализацией `C# Runtime` вызов `GC.Collect()` может вообще ничего не делать и это будет соответствовать стандарту.

---

Если рассуждать чуть ближе к практике, то в этой ситуации оба из объектов `Random` будут помечены как **возможные для удаления.**

Первый - по очевидным причинам, второй - т.к `WeakReference` будет указывать на объект, более не доступный ни по одному из `codepath` *(да и сам объект `WeakReference` также оказывается недоступным после выхода из соответствующего блока).*

А вот что происходит дальше, уже **implementation specific**, т.к совершенно неизвестно, что `GC` будет делать с объектами, возможными для удаления. Он может отложить их на следующий вызов сборщика, может поместить в какую-либо свою дополнительную внутреннюю очередь и т.п. Возможен, разумеется, очевидный вариант, когда оба объекта просто будут удалены.

---

Ситуация также осложняется тем, что оптимизатор может решить, что выгоднее аллокировать переменные `Random` **на стеке**, нежели в хипе. Что, естественно, делает вопрос о сборке мусора неактуальным.